# What determines whether `pg_dump` includes a varchar length?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I work on a project where we regularly dump our Postgres database schema and commit it in the project repository. However, depending on which developer dumps the schema (via `pg_dump`), varchar columns may be given without a length:

```
email character varying NOT NULL
```

or with a length:

```
email character varying(255) NOT NULL
```

Is there a configuration option that determines whether the length is included in the schema dump?

Comment: If the length exists, it gets included. I'd bet a beer that your devs are not dumping the same schema.

Answer (score -1):

From the docco [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-character.html), it says that

> The notations varchar(n) and char(n) are aliases for character
>   varying(n) and character(n), respectively. character without length
>   specifier is equivalent to character(1). **If character varying is
>   used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size.
>   The latter is a PostgreSQL extension.**

Note the bit in **bold**. Your email fields with `CHARACTER VARYING` without a length are like `TEXT` fields. This is not good practice - you really only should set fields to this if you really don't know the longest possible value. From the correct answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717573/what-is-the-longest-possible-email-address), it's 254 characters. This area is treated well in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying) (also check out the link within the correct answer).

[EDIT]

Of course, as @DanielVérité points out, these are not the same fields from the same table - my answer was predicated on the first being the `email` in table_x and the second being the `email` in table_y. If they're meant to be the same field in the same table, someone has made a mistake, perhaps not huge, but there's a problem.

It's better to have `CHARACTER VARYING(254)` or `VARCHAR(254)` for all email fields. That way, if you attempt to put more than 254 characters into the email field, PostgreSQL will throw an error:

```
test=# create table x(y varchar(4));
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into x values('sadfsadfa');
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(4)
test=# select * from x;
 y 
---
(0 rows)

test=#
```